# Overriding function with generics in kotlin

Tags: function, generics, overriding, kotlin

For example I have following sample code

```
fun f<T>( cb: (T, Int) -> Unit ): Unit {
  println("f called with cb which accepts 2 arguments"); 
}

fun f<T>( cb: (T) -> Unit ): Unit {
  println("f called with cb which accepts 1 argument"); 
  f<T> {item, position -> cb(item) }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  f { item -> }
  f { item, position -> }
}
```

Obliviously I want `f` function choose right implementation depends on amount of arguments I'm going to pass to closure

Currently **k**ompiller gives me error:

```
(8, 7) : Overload resolution ambiguity: 
internal fun <T> f(cb: (T, kotlin.Int) -> kotlin.Unit): kotlin.Unit defined in root package
internal fun <T> f(cb: (T) -> kotlin.Unit): kotlin.Unit defined in root package
```

Code in online sandbox: http://kotlin-demo.jetbrains.com/?publicLink=100745728838428857114-628607155

Compiller version: **org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.10.770**

---

UPD: related issue on youtrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6939

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report to the tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT#newissue

Comment: The error message is different now (compiler version 0.11.693): "Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T> f(cb: (T) -> kotlin.Unit): kotlin.Unit
Please specify it explicitly." 
Which make sense to me :)

Comment: @miensol but it still not works as expected :/

Comment: @ruX Well I'm new to Kotlin so maybe it's a stupid question but what would you expect the type of `item` to be inside `f { item -> /* here */ }` in first line in main, when it executed (assuming it compiled)?

Comment: @miensol you are right, thanks for the right question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @miensol I realized it was my mistake. I forgot to specify type for T while calling `f()`.

Fixed code:

```
fun f<T>( cb: (T, Int) -> Unit ): Unit {
  println("f called with cb which accepts 2 arguments"); 
}

fun f<T>( cb: (T) -> Unit ): Unit {
  println("f called with cb which accepts 1 argument"); 
  f<T> {item, position -> cb(item) }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  f<String> { item -> }
  f<Boolean> { item, position -> }
}
```